# How do i change the tags and taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy, tags

Ok i found the code to change the "TAGS" to another name..

I changed my tags to say "Celebrities" but the permalinks still says TAGS i want it to say "Celebrities" how do i do this.

Here is the code i use

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpa4182_init'); 
function wpa4182_init()
{
global $wp_taxonomies;

// The list of labels we can modify comes from
//  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy
//  http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L350
$wp_taxonomies['post_tag']->labels = (object)array(
    'name' => 'WPA 4182 Tags',
    'singular_name' => 'WPA 4182 Tag',
    'search_items' => 'Search WPA 4182 Tags',
    'popular_items' => 'Popular WPA 4182 Tags',
    'all_items' => 'All WPA 4182 Tags',
    'parent_item' => null, // Tags aren't hierarchical
    'parent_item_colon' => null,
    'edit_item' => 'Edit WPA 4182 Tag',
    'update_item' => 'Update WPA 4182 Tag',
    'add_new_item' => 'Add new WPA 4182 Tag',
    'new_item_name' => 'New WPA 4182 Tag Name',
    'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separata WPA 4182 tags with commas',
    'add_or_remove_items' => 'Add or remove WPA 4182 tags',
    'choose_from_most_used' => 'Choose from the most used WPA 4182 tags',
);

$wp_taxonomies['post_tag']->label = 'WPA 4182 Tags';
}
```

but the permalinks still say "tag" why is that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your tag base differently in the admin area: `Settings > Permalinks` then at the bottom there is a field for "Tag Base".  Enter "celebrities" in that field and your tag pages will be `yoursite.com/celebrities/some-celeb-name`.

As far as why that is, it's because the write rules -- `register_taxonomy` does more than just assign labels -- haven't been changed in your example above.  Also, tags are special: WordPress gives you the option to change the base.  So whatever the user puts in that field is going to override what you change the rewrite to be.